# Connection State open Method in .Net

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, sql-server-2008, connection

I am using .net, i have doubt about SqlConnection open

```
  sqlconnection con = new sqlconnection("Constr");

    if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed) ||( con.State == ConnectionState.Broken)
    { con.open();}
```

this method now am using this method is best or some programmers using below method

```
if (con.State == ConnectionState.Open)
{ con.close();}
con.open();
```

which one is best or which is best

Answer (score 2):

Why you dont use `using`?

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection (...))
{

}
```

I can this way is better.Also you can use this code:

```
if (conn != null && conn .State == ConnectionState.Closed)
{

}
```

Comment: you know what different between